# Richfaces 4 – extendedDataTable inbuilt filtering – selectionListner is not able to get the updated index after filtering is applied

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

Richfaces 4 – extendedDataTable inbuilt filtering – selectionListner() is not able to get the updated index after filtering is applied.
In Richfaces 3 there was DataModel class which is not present  in richfaces 4. 
**Which is the best way to implement table filtering in Richfaces 4, so that the selectionListner() also works correctly.**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
import org.richfaces.component.UIExtendedDataTable;
import org.richfaces.demo.tables.model.cars.InventoryItem;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ExtTableSelectionBean implements Serializable {
private String selectionMode = "multiple";
private Collection<Object> selection;
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{carsBean.allInventoryItems}")
private List<InventoryItem> inventoryItems;
private List<InventoryItem> selectionItems = new ArrayList<InventoryItem>();

public void selectionListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    UIExtendedDataTable dataTable = (UIExtendedDataTable) event.getComponent();
    Object originalKey = dataTable.getRowKey();
    selectionItems.clear();
    for (Object selectionKey : selection) {
        dataTable.setRowKey(selectionKey);
        if (dataTable.isRowAvailable()) {
            selectionItems.add((InventoryItem) dataTable.getRowData());
        }
    }
    dataTable.setRowKey(originalKey);
}

public Collection<Object> getSelection() {
    return selection;
}

public void setSelection(Collection<Object> selection) {
    this.selection = selection;
}

public List<InventoryItem> getInventoryItems() {
    return inventoryItems;
}

public void setInventoryItems(List<InventoryItem> inventoryItems) {
    this.inventoryItems = inventoryItems;
}

public InventoryItem getSelectionItem() {
    if (selectionItems == null || selectionItems.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return selectionItems.get(0);
}

public List<InventoryItem> getSelectionItems() {
    return selectionItems;
}

public void setSelectionItems(List<InventoryItem> selectionItems) {
    this.selectionItems = selectionItems;
}

public String getSelectionMode() {
    return selectionMode;
}

public void setSelectionMode(String selectionMode) {
    this.selectionMode = selectionMode;
}
}
```

Comment: Is there anyone who can help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this problem is because of the `@ViewScoped`.

Try using `@SessionScoped` and should solve your issue.